# Now I try to train my neural network for detection. In train loop I have troubles with " outputs = model(...)" string

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, object-detection

this is my first project for object detection from scratch. I use Colab, PyTorch, PIL and others. Load pretrained Faster R-CNN and add detector, which consist of linear, relu, dropout and another one linear. Data load from folders in my Google.Drive, I type my code below (Dataset class and train loop).

```
class BurgerDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, image_folder, annotation_folder, transform=None):
        self.image_folder = image_folder
        self.annotation_folder = annotation_folder
        self.transform = transform
        self.image_names = os.listdir(image_folder)
        self.annotation_names = os.listdir(annotation_folder)
        
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.image_names)
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):   # 2 != 3
        image_name = self.image_names[index]
        annotation_name = os.path.splitext(image_name)[0] + ".json"
        
        image_path = os.path.join(self.image_folder, image_name)
        annotation_path = os.path.join(self.annotation_folder, annotation_name)
        
        image = Image.open(image_path).convert("RGB")
        with open(annotation_path, "r") as file:
            data = json.load(file)
        annotations = data["annotations"]
        
        targets = []
        labels = []
        for annotation in annotations:
            box = annotation["bbox"]
            label = annotation["category_id"]
            targets.append(box)
            labels.append(label)
        
        targets = torch.FloatTensor(targets)
        labels = torch.LongTensor(labels)
        
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        
        return image, targets, labels
```

This is train loop:

```
num_epochs = 10
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
model = model.to(device)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001)

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    model.train()
    train_loss = 0
    for images, targets, labels in train_dataloader: 
        images = images.to(device)
        targets = targets.to(device)
        labels = labels.to(device)

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(images, targets)['pred']
        loss = your_loss_function(outputs, targets, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        train_loss += loss.item()

    train_loss /= len(train_dataloader)

    model.eval()
    test_loss = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for images, targets in test_dataloader:
            images = images.to(device)
            targets = targets.to(device)

            outputs = model(images)
            loss = your_loss_function(outputs, targets)

            test_loss += loss.item()

    test_loss /= len(test_dataloader)

    print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{num_epochs}, Train Loss: {train_loss:.4f}, Test Loss: {test_loss:.4f}")
```

This is my error:

AssertionError: targets should not be none when in training mode

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. I think you might be using [this model](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/models/generated/torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn.html#torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn). If that's the case, according to the docs, your problem is that you need to pass in a `target` dictionary with the `"boxes"` and `"labels"` keys leading to the relevant items:

> During training, the model expects both the input tensors and a
> targets (list of dictionary), containing:
>
> `boxes (FloatTensor[N, 4])`: the ground-truth boxes in `[x1, y1, x2, y2]`
> format, with `0 <= x1 < x2 <= W and 0 <= y1 < y2 <= H`.
>
> `labels (Int64Tensor[N])`: the class label for each ground-truth box